# Flask отказывается вставлять видео через URL из-за Сookie Samesite

Tags: flask, url, cookie, видео, ссылка

Имеется простой код на Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def homepage():
   return render_template('Flask_Test.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

А так же шаблон Flask_Test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flask_test</title>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Video</h1>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGfA-yfPudU" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

При запуске выходит так, что youtube отказывается давать видео:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так же консоль браузера Выдаёт ошибку:

**Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site context by specifying its SameSite attribute**

Как я понял, мне предлагают поменять параметры в куки файлах, которые приходят от ютуба, но как это сделать? Возможно ли решить проблему другим путём?

Comment: А зачем вы пытаетесь встроить страницу, которая в принципе не предназначена для встраивания? Чем вам не угодил код для встраивания, который предоставляет сам youtube?

Comment: Я всё понял, нужна специальная ссылка от ютуба, так же видеоклипы с музыкой он не вставляет из-за авторских прав.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь SECRET KEY через

`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Твой секретный ключ'


@app.route('/')
def homepage():
   return render_template('Flask_Test.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`

Comment: Непонятно, как это поможет в данном случае